# My redbud tree in Maine

Tags: trees, growth

I planted my redbud 3 years ago, 2 years they have had lots of leaves no buds.  This year there are no leaves at all, around the base of the tree there are little twigs growing with small leaves. Is my tree dead?

Comment: Hi there, without a picture or two we can't really tell.  Help us with more information and we can help you better

Comment: Also - do you remember the lowest temperature in your area last winter?